# Bootstrap Tabs - streetview

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I came across this great little script, for loading gmap in bootstrap tabs, via stackoverflow.

The link: http://jsfiddle.net/B4zLe/49/

I tried making necessary changes to try and fire streetview into another tab, but all I get is a blank. Any kind soles help please.

This is my gmap code ( for the map )

```
var map;

jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.920728, 145.769219);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    console.dir(map);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    $('a[href="#themap"]').on('shown', function(e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

    $('#myTab a[href="#themap"]').on('shown', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(latlng);
    });
    var contentString = '<div id="iw_content">'+
                            '<h4>16/63 Mcleod Street , Cairns City</h4>'+
                            '<div class="iw_content_block">QLD 4870</div>'+
                            '<div class="iw_content_block">More listings from <a href="/agent/leona-bonsey-14/">Leona Bonsey</a></div>'
                        '</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                        });
    var iconBase = '/public/images/';
                        var myShadow = {
                          url: iconBase + 'shadow.png',
                          anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 34)
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            icon: iconBase + '422marker.png',
                            shadow: myShadow,
                            position: latlng,
                            title: "16/63 Mcleod Street, Cairns City, QLD, 4870"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                          infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });
});
});
```

A demo can be seen here http://www.422.com.au/property/apartment-qld-cairns+city-15032013172546

This is what I have for the streetview map ( unsuccesfully loading streetview )

```
function initialize() {

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.920728, 145.769219);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: latlng,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('street_canvas'),
      panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting this to work is waiting to actually initialize the map until the tab is shown. Rather than initializing the map on load of the window, call initialize inside of the on('shown') of the street view map tab.

check out this fiddle:

var map;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    $('a[href="#map"]').on('shown', function(e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
    $('a[href="#street"]').on('shown', function(e) {
        initialize(); //Call initialize here!
    });

});

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.920728, 145.769219);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: latlng,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom : 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('street_canvas'),
    panoramaOptions
  );
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4zLe/167/